# How to achieve this style of UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` to let the user type 4 numbers which are returned from text message.I have set `UITextField` style and background image correctly but have no idea how to arrange these four numbers nicely.What I want is this:
[image]

But the result is this:

[image]

Here is my setting for `UITextField`.
[image]

How to separate the numbers nicely when typing from the keyboard,Any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to use `NSKernAttributeName` attribute:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"1234"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@(30) range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
self.textField.attributedText = attributedString;
```

[image]

Comment: The text is fixed,how can I achieve this when user is typing the numbers?

Comment: @BensonTommy Text is fixed only in my example. You can dynamically change it. Just add necessary attribute to attributedText in text field

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you place four text fields in one view, give it rounded corners and add it to your view hierarchy. Your view will have your desired background, and your text fields will be transparent (clearColor).
Then, in your delegate, when in one textfield text entered, move your coursor to the next text field

Comment: It seems that the UIElement is a Segmented Control with custom drawing rather than a TextView

Comment: Well, author tells that these is UITextField. And Border Style corresponds to UITextField

Comment: Sorry to mention that the user can delete the wrong number